# Evaluate the following integrals:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Evaluate the integrals:
I =$\iiint(2x-y+z^2)dV$
where V is the ellipsoid $3x^2 +4y^2 + 5z^2 = 17.$

I tried converting the equation of the ellipsoid to Spherical Coordinates and
got to 3$\rho^2cos^2\theta sin^2\phi + 4\rho^2sin^2\theta sin^2\phi  +5\rho^2cos^2\theta.$

However, I was not sure how to continue after this.

Comment: Do you know how to use the Jacobian and integrate?